# SVG Path showing bottom edge at certain viewport widths

Tags: ios, svg, safari, border

I'm working with a SVG path which paints a curve and fills it in.

The problem is at some viewport widths, the SVG element's bottom edge is displayed, only by a pixel or two, but with contrasting colors, it's very noticeable.

The issue does not appear using chrome or firefox on mac, on Safari.  It does effect safari, chrome and firefox on iOS, both iPhone and iPad, landscape or portrait.

Note: pink used to highlight the issue, normally would be white.

Full SVG Width showing edge
[image: Full SVG Width showing edge]

Zoom SVG showing edge
[image: Zoom SVG showing edge]

Full SVG at slightly less wide of a viewport, not displaying bottom edge.
[image: Full SVG not showing edge]

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <svg class="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="10em">
        <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>...</div>
```

And the CSS styles:

```
svg {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
.curveUpColor  { background-color: deeppink;}
.curveUpColor path {
    fill: grey; 
    stroke: orange;
    stroke-width: 8px; 
}
```

[Example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/CG_Pilot/z08fqmLt/) though it's not producing the edge line within the fiddle.

See the issue yourself at the bottom of the 'header' image and in the grey footer of my [client's website](http://www.intuitivebythesea.com/about) and adjust the width of the safari window.

Any thoughts?

Regards,

Zephyr

Comment: I've also tried disable antialiasing using `shape-rendering=""` attribute, as well as trying different `preserveAspectRatio=""` attributes.

Comment: The pictures don't show up on the post, at least for me. Try to provide links to an external website with the pictures uploaded.

Comment: @koullislp the pics are posted and embedded thru Dropbox, and are displaying for me in both the SE iOS app and my browser.  I will provide the full url shortly when I've got a sec to update the post.